# salt sls to use dnsutil.hosts_append not working

Tags: salt-stack

I need to read the host entries from pillar file and update the /etc/hosts file accordingly

This is my simple sls file to update the /etc/hosts file.

```
#/srv/salt/splunk_dep/hosts.sls

dnsutil:
  dnsutil.hosts-append:
    - hostsfile: '/etc/hosts'
    - ip_addr: '10.10.10.10'
    - entries: 'hostname'
```

when i execute the sls file
**salt Minion-name state.apply splunk_dep/hosts**

### Getting the following error

```
      ID: dnsutil
Function: dnsutil.hosts-append
  Result: False
 Comment: State 'dnsutil.hosts-append' was not found in SLS 'splunk_dep/hosts'
          Reason: 'dnsutil.hosts-append' is not available.
 Started:
Duration:
 Changes:
```

If i execute through command line its working fine

**salt 'DS-110' dnsutil.hosts_append /etc/hosts 10.10.10.10 hostname**

I need to update the /etc/hosts file through sls file. Can someone please help me on this.

I am using the salt version  : salt 2015.8.3 (Beryllium)

Comment: Hello Bala, since you confirmed that ahus1 answer is working, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`dnsutil` is a Salt module, and not a Salt state. Therefore it can be used from the command line, but not directly via SLS state file.

To run modules from state file you'll need [`module.run`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html). Please note that in this case you'll need to put an underscore in `hosts_append`, not a hyphen.

```
dnsutil:
  module.run:
    - name: dnsutil.hosts_append
    - hostsfile: '/etc/hosts'
    - ip_addr: '10.10.10.10'
    - entries: 'hostname'
```

Some caveats with modules: even if they don't change your system, they will be reported as "changed" in the summary of your salt call. Please consider using `file.blockreplace` for managing hosts file instead to avoid this.